# locating html elements with selenese in a test

Tags: testing, selenium, playframework

while writing some acceptance tests for my webapp (playframework based),I got confused by the usage of some selenium commands.

In my html page,I have a submit button like this

```
<input type="submit" id="removecartitem" value="remove"/>
```

to locate this,I used

```
assertElementPresent(id='removecartitem')
```

however,this fails,

```
assertElementPresent    id='removecartitem' false
```

The [selenium documentation](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#locators) says

> id=id: Select the element with the specified @id attribute.

but,if i simply put

```
assertElementPresent('removecartitem')
```

Then,the test is executed correctly.This is the source for confusion, since the default way is to select the element whose name attribute is 'removecartitem' ,and I haven't mentioned any name attribute in my html

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: do you need to remove the single quotes around 'removecartitem'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to remove the single quotes according to the documentation you provided...e.g:

```
assertElementPresent(id=removecartitem)
```